# Extjs: How to fire event on tree icon

Tags: extjs

My tree is loading very slow due to onclick of each node there is creation of tabpanel in the centerpanel.Now, i want to change the code like on node/icon click load only child nodes. on double click of node load the tab panel. i.e i want to load my tree first.

```
treePanel.on('expand',function(node){
    alert("Expand event")
    var iconClass=node.getUI().getIconEl().className;
    node.getUI().getIconEl().className="x-tree-node-icon loading_icon";
    var ajaxReq = ajaxRequest(node.attributes.url,0,"GET",true);

    ajaxReq.request({
        success: function(xhr) {
            var response=Ext.util.JSON.decode(xhr.responseText);
            appendChildNodes(response.nodes,node); //method to add child nodes
            node.expand();
            node.getUI().getIconEl().className=iconClass;

        },
        failure: function(xhr){
            Ext.MessageBox.alert( _("Failure") , xhr.statusText);
            node.getUI().getIconEl().className=iconClass;
        }
    });

});
rootNode.firstChild.fireEvent('expand',rootNode.firstChild);
```

Comment: I have no idea what you really want here, provide some code and I may remove the downvote.

Comment: I want to add child nodes on click of tree icon. And node click i want to add the tabpanel in the center. I tried with the above code. It is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can catch before load:

`tree.on( 'beforeload', function( oStore, oOperation, oOpts ) { }`

Load:

`tree.on( 'load', function( oStore, oNode, oNodes ) { }`

For icons:

`tree.on( 'expand', function( oNode, arChildren ) { }`

Then get a node and change icon:

`oNode.set('icon', ... );`

Comment: It dint work for me. On click of tree icon (ie folder\+\- icon)expand event dint occur.I have attached the code above. Please check

Comment: am waiting. Any one have idea. :(

Comment: Does your success callback fire or your failure? If success, what is in `response`? Do you get valid node data?

Comment: Both are not called. It is not going to that expand event at all on icon click.